# how to web scraping - beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a list from this link with "Title and price" for each product - https://www.price.ro/preturi_notebook-1193.htm but I'm not able to merge these two list in one like below:

"Title  Price"

I did something in my code, but I'm stuck in merge these two columns

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_link = 'https://www.price.ro/preturi_notebook-1193.htm'
page = requests.get(url_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title=soup.findAll('a',{'class':"titlu"})
price=soup.findAll('a',{'class':"price"})

for t in title:
    print(t.text.strip())
for p in price:
    print(p.text.strip())`
```

**Expected output:**

```
Asus ZenBook UX430UA-GV340R                        3,579.00 lei
Asus ZenBook  ux331fal-eg006t                      3,298.99 lei
Asus UX334FL-A4005T                                8,403.98 lei
Asus UX461FA-E1035T                                3,292.95 lei
Lenovo IdeaPad S530-13IWL  81j7004grm              3,499.00 lei
Asus ZenBook 13  UX331FN-EG003T                    5,229.00 lei
Asus UX334FL-A4014R                                3,692.28 lei
Asus FX705GM-EW137                                 4,460.96 lei
Asus S330FA-EY095                                  4,174.00 lei
Asus UX333FA-A4109                                 5,794.00 lei
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: i've modified the post, please see the "expected output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`produs-lista` to find all `product` list and iterate list of product and scrape title and price of each product.

**Ex.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_link = 'https://www.price.ro/preturi_notebook-1193.htm'
page = requests.get(url_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
produs_list = soup.find("div",{'class':'produse'}).find_all("div",\
               {'class':'produs-lista'})
data = []
for x in produs_list:
    title = x.find("a",{'class':'titlu'}).text.strip()
    price = x.find("a",{'class':'price'}).text.strip()
    product = dict(title=title,price=price)
    data.append(product)

print(data)
```

**O/P:**

```
[{'title': 'Asus ZenBook UX430UA-GV340R', 'price': '3,292.95 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus ZenBook  ux331fal-eg006t', 'price': '3,499.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus UX334FL-A4005T', 'price': '5,229.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus UX461FA-E1035T', 'price': '3,692.28 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Lenovo IdeaPad S530-13IWL  81j7004grm', 'price': '4,460.96 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus ZenBook 13  UX331FN-EG003T', 'price': '4,174.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus UX334FL-A4014R', 'price': '5,794.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus FX705GM-EW137', 'price': '5,885.48 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus S330FA-EY095', 'price': '3,279.46 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus UX333FA-A4109', 'price': '4,098.99 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Apple The New MacBook Pro 13 Retina (mpxr2ze/a)', 'price': '6,040.67 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Lenovo Legion Y530 81FV003MRM', 'price': '3,098.99 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus UX433FA-A5046R', 'price': '3,699.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'HP ProBook 450 G6 5TL51EA', 'price': '3,299.99 lei'},
 {'title': 'Asus X542UA-DM525', 'price': '2,424.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th gen 20KH006JRI', 'price': '10,202.99 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus VivoBook  X540UA-DM972', 'price': '1,659.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Asus X507UA-EJ782', 'price': '2,189.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'Apple MacBook Air 13 (mqd32ze/a)', 'price': '3,998.00 lei'}, 
{'title': 'HP ProBook 470 G5  2rr84ea', 'price': '4,460.49 lei'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can zip title and price,

```
for x in zip(title,price):
print(x[0].text.strip(),x[1].text.strip())
```

this will be the output:

Asus ZenBook UX430UA-GV340R 7,998.99 lei
Asus ZenBook  ux331fal-eg006t 7,650.85 lei
Asus UX334FL-A4005T 3,598.99 lei
Asus UX461FA-E1035T 3,292.95 lei
Lenovo IdeaPad S530-13IWL  81j7004grm 3,499.00 lei
Asus ZenBook 13  UX331FN-EG003T 5,229.00 lei
Asus UX334FL-A4014R 3,692.28 lei
Asus FX705GM-EW137 4,460.96 lei
Asus S330FA-EY095 4,174.00 lei
Asus UX333FA-A4109 5,794.00 lei
Apple The New MacBook Pro 13 Retina (mpxr2ze/a) 5,885.48 lei
Lenovo Legion Y530 81FV003MRM 3,279.46 lei
Asus UX433FA-A5046R 4,098.99 lei
HP ProBook 450 G6 5TL51EA 6,040.67 lei
Asus X542UA-DM525 3,098.99 lei
Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th gen 20KH006JRI 3,699.00 lei
Asus VivoBook  X540UA-DM972 3,299.99 lei
Asus X507UA-EJ782 2,424.00 lei
Apple MacBook Air 13 (mqd32ze/a) 10,202.99 lei
HP ProBook 470 G5  2rr84ea 1,659.00 lei

Answer (score 0):

You should change the for with this:

```
for index in range(len(title)):
    print("{}    {}".format(title[index].text.strip()))
```

You can do it since the number of prices and titles are the same.

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your lists using the zip-function, and generate a new list on the go (Using a list comprehension):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_link = 'https://www.price.ro/preturi_notebook-1193.htm'
page = requests.get(url_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title=list(soup.findAll('a',{'class':"titlu"}))
price=list(soup.findAll('a',{'class':"price"}))


#Merge lists using the zip() function, generate a new list of tuples with a list compehension
zippedlist = [(ttl, prce) for ttl, prcein zip(title,price)] 
#print(zippedlist)
```